# when using double buffering to draw image on canvas, cannot get the complete image?

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas, drawimage, html5boilerplate

this is my code, i use two canvas to drawimage to avoid flickering, but i cant get the full image when use this way, anyone can help please? 
if i only use one canvas the image display fine, it seems the secondarycanvas that created by Javascript got some issue to display the image, but i can't find what's wrong. any help is appreciated!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Decorate</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="content-box">
<canvas id="canvas" width="360" height="740" style="border:1px solid #d3d3d3"></canvas>

</div>
<script>
var c=document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");

var secondaryCanvas=document.createElement("canvas");
var secondaryCtx=secondaryCanvas.getContext("2d");
secondaryCanvas.weight=c.weight;
secondaryCanvas.height=c.height;
var bgimg=new Image();
bgimg.src=imageEncoder[24].background;
bgimg.onload=function() {
secondaryCtx.drawImage(bgimg, 0, 0);
ctx.drawImage(secondaryCanvas,0,0);
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: weight? did you mean width?

Comment: What happens when you run this code?  What are the expected results?  What are the actual results?  Consider using the code snippet editor to turn this into a working example that reproduces the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I change `secondaryCanvas.weight=c.weight;` to `secondaryCanvas.width=c.width;` and your code seems to work now.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Decorate</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="content-box">
<canvas id="canvas" width="360" height="740" style="border:1px solid #d3d3d3"></canvas>

</div>
<script>
var c=document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");

var secondaryCanvas=document.createElement("canvas");
var secondaryCtx=secondaryCanvas.getContext("2d");

secondaryCanvas.width=c.width;
secondaryCanvas.height=c.height;



var bgimg=new Image();
bgimg.src= "https://picsum.photos/360/740"
bgimg.onload=function() {
secondaryCtx.drawImage(bgimg, 0, 0);
ctx.drawImage(secondaryCanvas,0,0);
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```